# Finance - Initial Price of Swaption

Tags: statistics, finance

I have a question from Coursera Financial Engineering class

n=10-period binomial model for the short-rate
The lattice parameters are: 
r(0,0)=5%
u=1.1
d=0.9
q=0.5
1−0.5

**Compute the initial price of a swaption that matures at time t=5 and has a strike of 0.** The underlying forward starting swap begins at t=1, with maturity t=10 and fixed rate of 4.5%. (assume notional is $1M and you receive floating and pay fixed) Underlying forward starting swap is equal to 33,374

Comment: Welcome to math SE. First, have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions. Second, what have you tried?